# Roundcube+IIS7+PHP - No good error msg - Failure uploading attachment > 1.6MB

Tags: php, iis-7, email-attachments, roundcube

**Scenario**: Running Roundcube + IIS 7 + Php 5.4.4 + Hmailserver on a Win7 ultimate machine.

I've spent countless hours searching, and I still can't figure out if this is a IIS problem, PHP, or Roundcube problem.. especially since I can't find a decent error msg in any log file.

**Problem**: I can't seem to attach a file in roundcube larger than 1.6MB. The only message I get is File Upload Failed. I have looked in the IIS logs, the roundcube logs, and the php logs to no avail! Is there another way I can get a verbose diagnostic error here? (I only included HMailserver to give a full outlook, but it is not involved in the equation as roundcube is configured to use an external server for smtp).

```
PHP.INI settings:
    post_max_size = 200M;
    upload_max_filesize = 20M;
    Max_file_uploads = 20
    memory_limit = 256M;
```

The full phpinfo() is in a pdf file I uploaded here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09856336041349051907

Thanks.

---

**Update #1:**

I can verify that the files being uploaded as an attachment, are being fully uploaded and stored in the wwwroot/temp directory. Once uploaded however, the error occurs, and the files are left in the temp directory.

also, very strange.. this is in my php error log... However.. THESE FILES DO EXIST IN THOSE DIRECTORIES!!

[08-Sep-2015 21:13:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4.4\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

[08-Sep-2015 21:13:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4.4\ext\php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

[08-Sep-2015 21:13:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4.4\ext\php_com_dotnet.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.. I figured it out! I did an experiment and created a simple php upload form. It was succcessful. This pointed to a problem soley with roundcube. I disabled plugins until I found the culprit "filesystem_attachments". That's it.. problem solved :)